# Image Cache Generation

Tags: magento2.3, product-images, cache

I have recently discovered a issue with my Magento 2.3.0 image cache generation. I don't actually know when the problem started happening. Only thing of note that I have been doing is importing a large number of SKU's and images into the site. This led to a issue where around 5k extra images got imported, which upon cleaning up these duplicates I decided to flush the image cache and discovered the issue.

Issue Recreation Steps:

After flushing/deleting cached images from `/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/*`, and navigating to a product page. The base image fails to display. Loading a page with the console we get this error:
[image]
cache/9d089../w/o/woca9216.jpg 500 (Internal Server Error)

Now the weird thing is this only happens for the product image(base). Thumbnails after clearing **DO** get created again.

Things I've tried:

The basics: Setup:upgrade,static-content-deploy. Cache flushing, Reindexing. File permissions(My first thought, I've triple checked and it looks fine. Plus thumbnails are still getting created in the location.)

Symptom fix but no cure: **catalog:images:resize**, Now this does run, and makes images in the cache like it should. BUT I'm on a shared host....Therefore Limitations. Host timesout the script after 5min. I have 10k images and this would take way to long anyway. The fix is temporary for the ones I've tested with it getting to in time.

Beating my Head against the wall:
So. Learning the default Magento image flow taken from another contributor.

> Default Magento flow is whenever it load image(media), it will always
>   pass through the request to pub/get.php and check whether the image
>   exists or not. If it not exist, it will generate a new cached image.
>   If it exists, it will return that path. So by default image should
>   generate on page load.

So I check that `pub/media/.htaccess` has:

```
   ## rewrite everything else to index.php
        RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Also to check my `pub/get.php` I added this to the first line.

```
echo "test";exit;
```

Loading up a product page that should pull **get.php**, Nothing displayed. This is were I lose some people with the same issue. My permissions are fine, I have .htaccess in `pub/media/`and it includes the right info.
Any one have any clue why **get.php** would not be loading?
What am I missing?
Everything else on the site has been working great.

*Note: I did create a new item and add a image. Then clear its image from the cache. It will also not reload the image.
*Second Note: I do know the cache was working correctly in the past. Just not sure how long.

Comment: TLDR: Base images only are not being generated in cache.

Comment: I have the same issue in a newly upgraded Magento 2.3.6 version. Did you ever manage to get to the bottom of this? I even tried to move the .htaccess rewrite to the .htaccess file in the pub folder, I do get an exit in the get.php but nothing further...